# Using normal classes with vue composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

how can I use **framework-independent** JavaScript class instances with reactive state on vue-composition-api.

Given following class:

```
// CounterService / counter-service.ts
//
// this is a normal javascript class which is independent of vue
export const counterService = new (class CounterService {
  private count: number = 0;

  // should cause all components that use `getCount` to react.
  addOne(): void {
    this.count++;
  }

  // should be reactive
  getCount(): number {
    return this.count;
  }
})()
```

Kind regards
Rozbeh Chiryai Sharahi

Answer (score 0):

most important hint: **Use reactive or ref on all components involved** (those that update and those that read).

```
// Component A / Counts.vue
<template>
  <div>{{services.counterService.getCount()}}</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { counterService } from 'counter-service.ts'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // You could also use ref, but i prefer to avoid the `.value`
    const services = reactive({
      counterService
    })

    return { services }
  }
});
</script>
```

```
// Component B / IncrementCountButton.vue
<template>
  <div @click="services.counterService.addOne()">Increment</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { counterService } from 'counter-service.ts'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // You could also use ref, but i prefer to avoid the `.value`
    const services = reactive({
      counterService
    })

    return { services }

  }
});
</script>
```

Kind regards
Rozbeh Chiryai Sharahi